# Generating a 3D mesh from a string in Python

Tags: python, 3d, mesh, open3d, pymesh

I am Looking for a way to turn a text string into a 3D mesh, that could then be further manipulated using relevant python libraries, such as pyMesh or open3D. I thought this should be a common feature but this proves more difficult than imagined.

Answer (score 1):

Found this create_text() function in Open3D's library:

http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.t.geometry.TriangleMesh.html#open3d.t.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_text